# Does Instant of Power help a grapple roll?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, grapple

Instant of Power gives a +4 enhancement bonus to an ally's next attack roll. Does this bonus apply to grapple checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say. The [official definition of grapple checks](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#grappleChecks) says that they are “like a melee attack roll.” How *much* like a melee attack roll, though, is anyone’s guess. Unfortunately, only your DM can answer this one, and only for your game.

For what it’s worth, Pathfinder, which is based on D&D 3.5e, is much more explicit about combat maneuver checks *actually being* attack rolls, and benefiting from from bonuses to attack rolls. And Paizo, Pathfinder’s publisher, has been extremely, shall we say, “conservative” with martial power in general. So if it works for them, that’s arguably a pretty strong case that it should work for 3.5e (where martial power is usually greater).

Comment: It's most definitely a *Special Attack*. The grapple definition get's it closer to a melee attack, but what else would a *Special Attack* be if not an attack?

Comment: @Wyrmwood Unfortunately, the game uses two different definitions of attack—sometimes it refers to any kind of offensive action (e.g. *invisibility*) and sometimes it refers to specifically a thing you do with a weapon or natural attack that involves an attack roll and damage roll and so on. The category Special Attack may well be referring to the latter, while *instant of power* refers to an attack roll specifically.